# Time complexity for finding the nth prime number

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity, primes

How can I find the time complexity for my code below:

```
    if (nprime == 1) return 2;
    if (nprime == 2) return 3;
    int count = 3;
    int primeNum = -1;
   
    for (int i = 5; count <= nprime; i += 2)
    {
        if (PrimeNumber.IsPrime(i))
        {
            primeNum = i;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

The function `IsPrime(i)` has a time complexity of *square root of `i`* (Because I will loop for *sqrt of `i`* times). So what is the total time complexity of finding the *n*th prime number?

Comment: One important thing to mention: this particular implementation is not the most optimal one. So, time complexity for this code seems to be `O(n * sqrt(n)))`, as already answered, but time complexity of finding the nth prime number can be better.

Comment: Let's say to find a 40th prime number, for loop will run way more than 40 times. Then how can we say O(n* sqrt(n)) ? Can you please help me understand that?

Comment: You are so right, indeed. It is more like `O(p * sqrt(p))` where `p` is the n-th prime number, which is unknown, but seems to grow with the speed of `O(n * log(n))`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev it's more like `O(n * sqrt(p))` because most of non-primes have small factors.

Comment: Or equivalently `O(p sqrt(p)/ln(p))`, which is improved to and precisely derived as `O(p sqrt(p)/ln(p)^2)`, in Section 2.1 of the article ["The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes"](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) by M.E. O'Neill. @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Answer (score 0):

It should be `O(n \sqrt(n))` as the loop iterates over `i` from `5` to `n`.